# How to get duplicate data like this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have data like this
[image]

And Category duplicate is
1.Duplicate base code if exist duplicate, result is by last step 
[image]
2.Duplicate base number1 or base number2 if exist duplicate, result is by last step

I need result like
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: The desired behavior that is being asked for in the query needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you're asking for, I believe that this achieves what you want.

It does produce the specified result, at least.

```
declare @Data table
(
    ID int not null,
    CODE varchar(3) not null,
    NUMBER1 varchar(3) not null,
    NUMBER2 varchar(3) not null,
    STEP int not null
)

insert into @Data values
    (1, 'XXA', '001', '009', 1),
    (2, 'XXB', '001', '008', 2),
    (3, 'XXC', '002', '009', 3),
    (4, 'XXA', '002', '008', 4)

-- this query returns the record with the highest STEP
-- excluding any other records that have the same CODE,
-- NUMBER1, or NUMBER2 and a lower STEP
select
    d.ID,
    d.CODE,
    d.NUMBER1,
    d.NUMBER2,
    d.STEP
from @Data d
where
    -- there does not exist any other record that has
    -- the same CODE, NUMBER1, or NUMBER2 and a higher STEP
    not exists (
        select 1
        from @Data duplicate
        where
            (
                duplicate.CODE = d.CODE
                or duplicate.NUMBER1 = d.NUMBER1
                or duplicate.NUMBER2 = d.NUMBER2
            )
            and (
                duplicate.STEP > d.STEP
                or (
                    duplicate.STEP = d.STEP
                    and duplicate.ID > d.ID
                )
            )
    )


-- this query returns the duplicate records with a lower STEP
select
    d.ID,
    d.CODE,
    d.NUMBER1,
    d.NUMBER2,
    d.STEP,
    HigherStep.ID as HigherStepID
from @Data d
inner join (
    -- join to the duplicate record that has a higher STEP
    select
        ID,
        CODE,
        NUMBER1,
        NUMBER2
    from @Data HighestStep
    where
        -- there does not exist any other record that has
        -- the same CODE, NUMBER1, or NUMBER2 and a higher STEP
        not exists (
            select 1
            from @Data duplicate
            where
                (
                    duplicate.CODE = HighestStep.CODE
                    or duplicate.NUMBER1 = HighestStep.NUMBER1
                    or duplicate.NUMBER2 = HighestStep.NUMBER2
                )
                and (
                    duplicate.STEP > HighestStep.STEP
                    or (
                        duplicate.STEP = HighestStep.STEP
                        and duplicate.ID > HighestStep.ID
                    )
                )
        )
) HigherStep on
    HigherStep.ID <> d.ID -- don't match this record to itself
    and (
        HigherStep.CODE = d.CODE
        or HigherStep.NUMBER1 = d.NUMBER1
        or HigherStep.NUMBER2 = d.NUMBER2
    )
```

---

Below is a revised query for retrieving the records with a lower step, based on Yusan's comment.  An issue with the query is that it would fail to capture records that are not immediate duplicates of those records with the highest step.

```
-- this query returns the duplicate records with a lower STEP
select
    d.ID,
    d.CODE,
    d.NUMBER1,
    d.NUMBER2,
    d.STEP,
    HigherStep.ID as HigherStepID
from @Data d
inner join (
    -- join to the duplicate record that has a higher STEP
    select
        ID,
        CODE,
        NUMBER1,
        NUMBER2,
        STEP
    from @Data
) HigherStep on
    (
        HigherStep.CODE = d.CODE
        or HigherStep.NUMBER1 = d.NUMBER1
        or HigherStep.NUMBER2 = d.NUMBER2
    )
    and (
        HigherStep.STEP > d.STEP
        or (
            HigherStep.STEP = d.STEP
            and HigherStep.ID > d.ID
        )
    )
```

Comment: And how to get reference duplicate with id so result additonal colum with value 1,2,3, Tanks before Doctor.

Comment: @Yusan - I'm not sure if I understood, but I've updated my answer to include a second query, which returns the duplicate records that were excluded by the first query.  The only difference is that I removed the `not` from the where clause.

Comment: @Yusan - my apologies, I messed up my previous edit to the answer. I've also revised the second query so that in addition to returning the records that were excluded by the first query, it also joins those records to the duplicate record that has the higher step.  The ID of that record is provided as the "HigherStepID" column.

Comment: I have problem if in there have stepp same so come 2 record duplicate in my table have transaction_date, i want take by last transaction if in there have same step. Tanks Doktor

Comment: @Yusan - What do you want in the case of a tie? Do you want to pick the record with the higher ID?  I have made that update to the queries in my answer.  I changed the condition `duplicate.STEP > HighestStep.STEP` to `duplicate.STEP > HighestStep.STEP or ( duplicate.STEP = HighestStep.STEP and duplicate.ID > HighestStep.ID )`

Comment: if i add like this insert into @Data values
    (1, 'XXA', '001', '003', 1),
    (2, 'XXB', '001', '008', 2),
    (3, 'XXC', '002', '009', 3),
    (4, 'XXA', '002', '008', 4),
    (5, 'XXA', '004', '003', 4),
    (6, 'XXF', '009', '004', 4),
    (7, 'XXG', '007', '004', 2) >>> i loss XXB and XXC can you review please

Comment: @Yusan - Your issue is because records 2 and 3 are duplicates of record 4, based on the NUMBER1 and NUMBER2 columns, but record 4 is a duplicate of record 5 based on the CODE column. I've revised my answer to include another query; this new query will return all of those records that are replaced by another record with a higher step. Note that some records will appear multiple times, because they are duplicates with multiple other records.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood right:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    CODE VARCHAR(50),
    NUMBER1 VARCHAR(50),
    NUMBER2 VARCHAR(50),
    STEP INT
)

INSERT INTO @T1(ID, CODE, NUMBER1, NUMBER2, STEP)
VALUES(1, 'XXA', '001', '009', 1)
INSERT INTO @T1(ID, CODE, NUMBER1, NUMBER2, STEP)
VALUES(2, 'XXB', '001', '008', 2)
INSERT INTO @T1(ID, CODE, NUMBER1, NUMBER2, STEP)
VALUES(3, 'XXC', '002', '009', 3)
INSERT INTO @T1(ID, CODE, NUMBER1, NUMBER2, STEP)
VALUES(4, 'XXA', '002', '008', 4)

SELECT      TAB.ID,
            TAB.CODE,
            TAB.NUMBER1,
            TAB.NUMBER2,
            TAB.STEP,
            COALESCE(CAST(DUP_CODE_T.ID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',', '') + 
            COALESCE(CAST(DUP_NUM1_T.ID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',', '') + 
            COALESCE(CAST(DUP_NUM2_T.ID AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS DUPLICATE_WITH
FROM        @T1 AS TAB OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT      TOP 1 DUP_CODE.ID
                FROM        @T1 AS DUP_CODE
                WHERE       DUP_CODE.CODE = TAB.CODE AND
                            DUP_CODE.ID <> TAB.ID
            ) AS DUP_CODE_T OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT      TOP 1 DUP_NUM1.ID
                FROM        @T1 AS DUP_NUM1
                WHERE       DUP_NUM1.NUMBER1 = TAB.NUMBER1 AND
                            DUP_NUM1.ID <> TAB.ID
            ) AS DUP_NUM1_T OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT      TOP 1 DUP_NUM2.ID
                FROM        @T1 AS DUP_NUM2
                WHERE       DUP_NUM2.NUMBER2 = TAB.NUMBER2 AND
                            DUP_NUM2.ID <> TAB.ID
            ) AS DUP_NUM2_T
```

You can add the WHERE clause or TOP 1 to filter the result.

Comment: Great.., But how to result only 1 row just by hight step. Tanks so much pistipanko.

Comment: Add TOP 1 and ORDER BY TAB.ID DESC.

Comment: i mean in data reality i have other data and that is unique so result not just 1 one with top 1, maybe other row is not have duplicate, tanks.

Comment: If you want just duplicate rows add WHERE TAB.DUPLICATE_WITH IS NOT NULL